# how to create a permission in application

Tags: android

I create a application, & I have many features in this application. So, i wanna this application shows these features to other applications. How can i do. Please answer me. thanks much much

Comment: Can you give us some more details, such as what operating system and programming language, which features, and so on?

Answer (score 0):

'I create a application' - lets suggest that 'this application' is Android apk file.

'I have many features in this application' - what type of features?

'So, i wanna this application shows these features to other applications.' - there are several ways to do it in Android - broadcast some event, or use content provider mechanics, you can share apk preferences, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is there : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html